# Macro needs to check 5 cells in row 

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone knows idea of my below problem in VBA excel

Macro needs to check 5 cells(Continues) in a 1 row.. Totally more than 500 rows are there ..if anyone cell color in a row has color “red” means it has to mention “new” in some column ..

Any idea or solution.. ??

i use the below code , to check any cell in single(or selected) column has red  ...

Does anyone knows idea of my below problem in VBA excel

Macro needs to check 5 cells(Continues) in a 1 row.. Totally more than 500 rows are there ..if anyone cell color in a row has color “red” means it has to mention “new” in some column ..

Any idea or solution.. ??

i use the below code for to check any cell in single has red  ...

```
Sub test()

    Dim erange as range

    for each erange in selection

        if erange.interior.color = red then
            Erange.offset(0,1)="New"
        end if 

    next erange

end if
```

Comment: And does that code run fine (I would have thought not)? Do you get an error?

Comment: Try to ensure it works by using **.Value**: `Erange.offset(0,1).Value="New"`

Comment: Ok, I've reread your question. Which cells do you want to check? Shos us a screenshot or at least how your data look alike

Comment: i use above code for to check one column(This code running well without error) .. Prob is if i need to check 5 column then results in single column .. How its possible..??? ..Suggest you ideas ..It  will be great help

Answer (score 1):

I planned on putting this as comments but then this would never fit in there.

> > > Does anyone knows idea of my below problem in VBA excel

There are 2 main errors in your code.

Firstly, `Red` doesn't evaluate to a valid color in Excel.

Change that line to

```
 if erange.interior.color = vbRed then
```

or

```
 If erange.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
```

And Secondly, you are missing an `End Sub`. Replace the last `end if` with an `End Sub`

Now to your main problem. The above code will not help you to check if 5 continuous cells have `Red` color. One way would be to use this logic

Loop through your range and set `erange` to consists of 5 cells For example if your range is A1:C10 then in your loop, your first range will be A1:A5 then A2:A6 and then A3:A7 and so on... Once you have your range then you check if each cell in the range has the color red. Hope this gives you a start.

Comment: Yes i know ... i use above code for to check one column(altered as you said)(This code running well without error) .. Prob is if i need to check 5 column then results in single column ..?????

Comment: Thank u Siddharth .. :) its helped me lot :)

Comment: I don't get the "offset"! I would expect that you put this in a fixed column outside the five columns you are checking. Aren't you overwriting data inside the five columns with "new". I would have used a cells(IncrementalRowNumber, FixedColumnNumber).value command...